# Pydev-pylint fix all errors at once

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pylint

I am using the pylint plugin in pydev (eclipse) to check for static errors in my code. Often there will be same type of errors in many places, for example, unused variable i. Is there a way to execute one corrective step for all such cases instead of going to each error location. In this case I would like to rename any such unused variable as dummy, all at once. There are other similar errors like unnecessary semi-colons (I also code a lot of c++ :( ) and unused imports, which I want to delete all at once.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are currently no such quick-fixes in PyDev. Please report that as a feature request.